# Mapping objects in database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to learn hibernate and going through a tutorial i was trying to implement OneToOne mapping. I have a Question and an Answer class/entity. I have mapped an Answer for a Question, below is the source code.

Question.java

```
package com.map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

@Entity
public class Question {

    @Id
    @Column(name="question_id")
    private int questionId;
    private String question;
    @OneToOne
    private Answer answer;
    
    public int getQuestionId() {
        return questionId;
    }
    public void setQuestionId(int questionId) {
        this.questionId = questionId;
    }
    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }
    public Answer getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(Answer answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public Question(int questionId, String question, Answer answer) {
        super();
        this.questionId = questionId;
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public Question() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Question [questionId=" + questionId + ", question=" + question + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer.java

```
package com.map;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @Column(name="answer_id")
    private int answerId;
    private String answer;
    public int getAnswerId() {
        return answerId;
    }
    public void setAnswerId(int answerId) {
        this.answerId = answerId;
    }
    public String getAnswer() {
        return answer;
    }
    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    public Answer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Answer(int answerId, String answer) {
        super();
        this.answerId = answerId;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Answer [answerId=" + answerId + ", answer=" + answer + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

Below is the MapDemo class to run the program.

```
package com.map;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class MapDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        
        Question q1 = new Question();
        q1.setQuestionId(1212);
        q1.setQuestion("What is Java");
        Answer answer = new Answer();
        answer.setAnswerId(343);
        answer.setAnswer("Java is programming laguage");
        q1.setAnswer(answer);
        
        Session s = factory.openSession();
        Transaction t = s.beginTransaction();
        s.save(q1);
        t.commit();
        s.close(); 
        
        
        factory.close();
    }
}
```

hibernate-cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC 
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
            <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
            <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</property>
            <property name="connection.username">system</property>
            <property name="connection.password">system</property>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <mapping class="com.tut.Student"></mapping>
            <mapping class="com.tut.Address"></mapping>     
            <mapping class="com.map.Question"></mapping>
            <mapping class="com.map.Answer"></mapping>      
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

When i try to run the program the error i see in logs is that the foreign key gets violated in Question entity which refers to an Answer but i set the Answer object in Question class object before trying to persist it. Does hibernate understand that it first needs to create entry in Answer table then refer it in question table? I am not sure how it works, I get this error but in tutorial the instructor did not. He is using MySQL and i am using Oracle database. Please advise.

Logs for the exception:

```
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.10.Final
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] at URL [jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe]
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=system}
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
Hibernate: drop table Answer cascade constraints
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@74b86971] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: drop table Question cascade constraints
Hibernate: drop table Student cascade constraints
Hibernate: drop table student_address cascade constraints
Hibernate: create table Answer (answer_id number(10,0) not null, answer varchar2(255 char), primary key (answer_id))
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@7a1b8a46] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Hibernate: create table Question (question_id number(10,0) not null, question varchar2(255 char), answer_answer_id number(10,0), primary key (question_id))
Hibernate: create table Student (id number(10,0) not null, course varchar2(255 char), duration varchar2(255 char), city varchar2(255 char), name varchar2(255 char), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table student_address (address_id number(10,0) generated as identity, addedDate date, CITY varchar2(100 char), image blob, IS_OPEN number(1,0), STREET varchar2(50 char), primary key (address_id))
Hibernate: alter table Question add constraint FKs6ghcwuovtcp489oo5dy7rvk5 foreign key (answer_answer_id) references Answer
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
Hibernate: select answer_.answer_id, answer_.answer as answer2_0_ from Answer answer_ where answer_.answer_id=?
Hibernate: insert into Question (answer_answer_id, question, question_id) values (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: update Question set answer_answer_id=?, question=? where question_id=?
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 2291, SQLState: 23000
Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FKS6GHCWUOVTCP489OO5DY7RVK5) violated - parent key not found

Dec 09, 2022 4:50:49 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1411)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at com.map.MapDemo.main(MapDemo.java:25)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:46)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3571)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3438)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3852)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:723)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FKS6GHCWUOVTCP489OO5DY7RVK5) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:629)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:563)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1150)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:298)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:497)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:151)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1051)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1530)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1310)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3745)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3917)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3896)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:991)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: Error : 2291, Position : 0, Sql = update Question set answer_answer_id=:1 , question=:2  where question_id=:3 , OriginalSql = update Question set answer_answer_id=?, question=? where question_id=?, Error Msg = ORA-02291: integrity constraint (SYSTEM.FKS6GHCWUOVTCP489OO5DY7RVK5) violated - parent key not found

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
    ... 36 more
```

Comment: Try saving the answer first OR add cascade to the relation, e.g. `@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)`.

Comment: It works but could you please explain why Cascade is required? Also why am i experiencing this and not the instructor in the video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have created and configured your entities, `Question` has the foreign key to `Answer`. *This is perfectly fine.* The exception thrown is because you ask JPA to save a question, which contains a FK to an answer that is not yet saved. The error message and the logs are a bit confusing I must admit, but this should be the reason.

One solution is to save the answer before the question manually. The other solution is to use the `cascade` instruction to the JPS one-to-one relation, so that *JPA will save the answer before the question for you*. Either of these should work:

```java
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) // cascade all operations
// -OR-
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST) // cascade the persist operation only
// -OR you can even specify many types
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.DELETE})
```

I haven't seen the video, but I am sure that if you check the details, there will be a subtle difference.